# Cleaning Google search results in R

Tags: html, regex, r, xpath

Brand new (like today) to both R and scraping, stackoverflow and tbh writing any sort of code so be gentle please.

I've managed to get a search to return an array (results) with all URLs from a Google search results page:

```
require(XML)
require(stringr)
xPath <- "//h3//a[@href]"

html <- getURL("http://google.com/search?q=site%3AneatlyformedpartofURL.com+somekeyword")   # read in page contents
doc <- htmlParse(html)    # parse HTML into tree structure
nodes <- xpathApply(doc, xPath, xmlAttrs)   # extract url nodes using XPath. 
results <- sapply(nodes, function(x) x[[1]])    # extract urls
free(doc)   # free doc from memory
results

[1] "/url?q=http://www.neatlyformedpartofURL.com/some-page-ref1/&sa=U&ei=iSr2U-KhA4LH7AaLy4Ao&ved=0CBQQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNFTW0cOKDsALw_3I8g7e-q_6kTJ6g"      
[2] "/url?q=http://www.neatlyformedpartofURL.com/some-page-ref2/&sa=U&ei=iSr2U-KhA4LH7AaLy4Ao&ved=0CBsQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNHtz7hGnkBlApSYLFgRr_baSTWldw"
```

BUT each result has junk before and after the actual URL.  I have also managed to strip all the gubbins using;

```
l1 <- unlist(strsplit(results, split='?q=', fixed=TRUE))[2] # strip everything before the http:// 
l2 <- unlist(strsplit(l1[2], split='/&sa', fixed=TRUE))[1]  # strip everything added by google after the url
```

Which will return:

```
[1] http://www.neatlyformedpartofURL.com/some-page-ref1
```

But that's it.  It looks to me like the unlist(strsplit... is only actioning on the first result from the results array.  I have a suspicion it may involve sapply but can anyone help me with the code to strip all the gubbins from all results in the array?

Ideally I should end up with...

```
   [1] http://www.neatlyformedpartofURL.com/some-page-ref1
   [2] http://www.neatlyformedpartofURL.com/some-page-ref2
```

Thanks awfully.

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you provide a minimal working example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: First of all, welcome to SO. You have provided a nice reproducible example and showed some effort, so good job on that! Last thing left to do is to provide us with your final desired result

Comment: Hopefully done and done.  Thanks for the welcome BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need in multiple `strsplit`s or `sapply`, just try the vectorized `gsub`

```
gsub("(/url[?]q=)|(/&sa.*)", "", results)
## [1] "http://www.neatlyformedpartofURL.com/some-page-ref1"
## [2] "http://www.neatlyformedpartofURL.com/some-page-ref2"
```

Comment: PERFECT!   Brilliant.  So the | is obviously an OR statement.  Would these mean I could add further statements were they needed?

Comment: Yes, as long as they are valid regex expressions. Take a look at `?regex`

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract(results, perl('(?<=\\=).*(?=\\/)'))
 #[1] "http://www.neatlyformedpartofURL.com/some-page-ref1"
 #[2] "http://www.neatlyformedpartofURL.com/some-page-ref2"
```